# Jordan Canonical Form of simple $2\times 2$ matrix complex

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let
$$A =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

**Original question**: determine the Jordan form of this matrix and its corresponding P matrix.

I understand all the steps I need to take to find the Jordan form, but how many times I try I can't seem to do this one the right way..

Using its characteristic polynomial I found that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $λ = 1 \pm i$.

I found the first eigenvector: $$\begin{pmatrix}
i \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Finding a generalized eigenvector is where I go wrong, I think.

I found: $$\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now we can make $P = [v_1\, v_2]$ to find $J$, where $J = (P^{-1})AP$

After computing this the matrix I get for $J$ is not a Jordan form.

The matrix I got is:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1-i & 1 \\
0 & 1+i \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Anyone who knows what I did wrong?

Edit: Changed the original question to: "Determine the Jordan form and P matrix" instead of "Determine the Jordan form".

Comment: You do not need to find any generalized eigenvectors, since each eigenvalue has multiplicity 1.

Comment: @MuratMetindoğan: The RREF of $ [A -(1+i) I]v_1 = 0$ is $$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & i \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)v_1 = 0$$ That makes the eigenvector easy and the other one is the complex conjugate. There is your $P$.

Comment: I finally got it! I was looking for a generalized eigenvector, when I didn't need to, since I have two eigenvalues. Stupid me. Thanks @arkeet

Comment: And thanks @Moo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have 2 distinct eigenvalues the matrix can be diagonalized and therefore the Jordan form is the diagonal matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1-i & 0 \\
0 & 1+i \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @MuratMetindoğan $P$ matrix contains the eigenvectors as columns.

Comment: Thank you @user I finally found my mistake.